B&R PLC How to do initial transfer without losing connection?
I'm encountering a problem with Initial transfer to a PLC. When connected it enters the BOOT mode and during the Initial transfer the PLC seems to lose previously set IP address and cannot reconnect. The info is: Target is being rebooted. Waiting for reconnection.
It never reconnects again.
this is the transfer popup
I am using Automation Studio, X20CP1684 PLC.
What should I do to be able to properly connect and perform Initial transfer? Thank you
I tried to do everything according to provided B&R tutorials, but nothing seems to help with this issue.

In case anyone else is having the same problem, it seems I found the solution: for the first initial transfer, you have to Activate Simulation. Then the transfer is successful and it enters the RUN mode.

I don't know B&R, but I had a similar problem with PLCs and HMIs where the IP address is set during the transfer process (the IDE would set the PLC IP to one that was in the project settings). The solution was to set the PLC IP manually (in the hardware or direct connection - such as USB or dip switch), then set the IP in the project exactly the same as what was set in the Hardware, this prevented the system from trying to set the IP during the transfer process.
Another process that helps in network transfer is to set a fixed IP on your computer port that is in the range of the PLC IP, for example: PLC: 192.168.10.4 / Your PC: 192.168.10.5

During initial transfer everything is deleted on PLC side and transfer new (IP address settings as well). So make sure that IP address set in your project is the same one you are connected to. Otherwise you have to cancel transfer after reboot and set connection from Automation Studio new. Check this tutorial I made recently. https://community.br-automation.com/t/getting-started-with-b-r-hello-community-first-project-backend-plc-part/4676
